# Weight Paint "sliders" not visible

Tags: weight-paint-mode

[image: where is my sliders?]

I was following a tutorial on weight painting. When I switch to Weight Paint mode, the sliders that are supposed to be on the top isn't there. I'm using Blender 2.93.13. Are the sliders only available on higher version or is there a setting or an option I need to toggle on?

[image: the slider i meant from the tutorial i was following]

Comment: Apart from what I show you in my answer below, as I can see by the "fps: 22.37" in your first screenshot, you had a playing animation at the moment you made the image, I don't think that was intentional, perhaps you just hit the spacebar accidentally. I just want to say that although in this case it has no effect on the sliders, but there are some settings/options that might not be available while the animation is playing.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Also i noticed i can also just right click with the draw tool selected and it brings the sliders too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the solution to your problem, but there is indeed an option that can be toggled on and off to make the sliders disappear: if you right-click on the editor window's header (that's the menu bar where it says "Weight Paint", "View", "Weights", not the top menu with "File", "Edit" etc.) you can toggle the option *Show Tool Settings* on/off.

[image: tool settings]